# Material derrivative or extracting/getting the vector component (sympy vector module)

Tags: python, vector, sympy

I am working on a project and I have to do some material derivatives. I can't find the function in the module which can do this type of operation for me. Even if this function does not exist I can make it myself but then there is another problem. I don't know how to extract a vector component from a vector. If I have a vector (5,10) I cant extract the y component alone (10) without bringing the x component next to it.

I read alot about similar problems on this forum and I also read the documentation for sympy vector module. I can't seem to find an answer.

```
import sympy.physics.vector
A = ReferenceFrame('A')
v = 5*A.x + 10*A.y
```

I'd like to do a material derivative of vector "v". If this isn't possible I would like to make a function myself (def fun...) but I also don't know how to get one component from a vector.

I imagined that the component extraction would looked something like v[0] or something similar but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As far as material derivatives go, you'd probably be best off writing your own function which shouldn't be too difficult. Otherwise you might be able to make use of other modules within `sympy.physics` such as the `mechanics` module. I'm not sure if it will help or not but it's definitely worth a look.

2) To your second question (how to extract the components of a sympy vector object):

This is a little hacky because once you convert to matrix form the underlying reference frame information is lost but you could do something like this:

```
from sympy.physics import vector

A = vector.ReferenceFrame('A')
v = 5*A.x + 10*A.y

x_component = v.to_matrix(A)[0]
y_component = v.to_matrix(A)[1]
```

If you still wanted it to be in vector form as opposed to just the scalar coefficient you could immediately re-multiply by the basis vector like such:

```
x_vec = (v.to_matrix(A)[0])*A.x
y_vec = (v.to_matrix(A)[0])*A.y
```